# Using SunSpot Solr, Over Ride Type So it Doesn't Match Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

What I would like to do is take a model that looks like this

```
class Principal < ApplicationRecord
  searchable do
    text    :name
  end
end
```

And then when I create or save this, I want the type that comes out of solr via sunspot to be something different like 'HeadmasterPrincipal' for example.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to wire up an after save hook on the Principal that would then instantiate a `HeadmasterPrincipal` and have the searchable block on that which would then send it to Solr.